# Erro na PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, sql

Sou novato em relação a criar PROCEDURE .
estou tentando criar esta PROCEDURE mais esta tando erro.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `P_lgs`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `P_lgs` ( idcod INT, dt VARCHAR(20), ip VARCHAR(20), msg VARCHAR(250), mail VARCHAR(250) ) 
BEGIN
  DECLARE numid INT DEFAULT 0;
  IF idcol <> 0 THEN 
    numid = idcol;
  END IF ;

  INSERT INTO `logs`(logs_cod,logs_dt,logs_ip,logs_mensagem,logs_email) VALUE(numid,dt,ip,msg,mail);
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Qual erro? Em que trecho?

Comment: Seria melhor você dar uma lida na documentação: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: @gmsantos o erro é na linha create procedure,

Comment: Query: drop procedure if exists `P_lgs`; create procedure `P_lgs` ( idcod int, dt varchar(20), ip varchar(20), msg varchar(250), mail v...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create procedure `P_lgs` ( idcod int, dt varchar(20), ip varchar(20), msg varcha' at line 2

Comment: @Welguri antes de criar novamente a procedure você precisa dropar a antiga...

Comment: @gmsantos mais antes do CREATE PROCEDURE, eu coloquei o DROP.

Comment: @Welguri porém com o delimitador `;` antigo. Tente alterar o delimitador para `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P_lgs//`

Answer (score 1):

@Welguri, tenta assim:

```
 BEGIN
  DECLARE numid INT DEFAULT 0
  IF idcol <> 0 THEN 
    numid = idcol

INSERT INTO `logs`(logs_cod,logs_dt,logs_ip,logs_mensagem,logs_email) VALUE(numid,dt,ip,msg,mail)
END //
```

Comment: O erro esta acontecendo na linha, CREATE PROCEDURE...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create procedure `P_lgs` ( idcod int, dt varchar(20), ip varchar(20), msg varcha' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

Desta forma **não** houve mais **erro**.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P_lgs;//
CREATE PROCEDURE P_lgs ( IN idcod INT, IN dt VARCHAR(20), IN ip VARCHAR(20), IN msg VARCHAR(250), IN mail VARCHAR(250) ) 
BEGIN
  DECLARE numID INT DEFAULT 0;
  IF idcol = '' THEN 
    SELECT numID=0;
  ELSE
    SELECT numID=idcol;
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO LOGS(logs_cod, logs_dt, logs_ip, logs_mensagem, logs_email) VALUES(numID, dt, ip, msg, mail);
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: A única diferença é o delimitador do drop ?